# specific error on :"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: vb.net

I've made a program by X-Copying from a computer model. By clicking a button it starts running and it goes so fine. But after its run process finished when I click that button again (without closing the program), it prompts the error :"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
I've written here the sub main that I X-Copied Visual studio:

```
Public Sub Main1(ByVal FileName As String)

    AddHandler myModel.Init, AddressOf OnInitilize
    AddHandler myModel.IterBottom, AddressOf OnIterationBottom
    AddHandler myModel.IterTop, AddressOf OnIterationTop
    AddHandler myModel.Converged, AddressOf OnIterationConverge
    AddHandler myModel.End, AddressOf OnFinished
    AddHandler myModel.OnMessage, AddressOf OnMessage
    AddHandler myModel.OnModsimError, AddressOf OnMessage
    XYFileReader.Read(myModel, FileName)
    Dim myModsim As New Modsim
    Csu.Modsim.NetworkUtils.ManageUnits.Unit_Conversion_Controller(myModel)
    myModsim.RunSolver(myModel)

End Sub
```

The error happens for "myModel"! I don't know why it's null referenced in the second run!

Comment: I don't think xcopy means what you think it means. Why are you using code you don't understand? What line are you getting the exception on?

Comment: I hope I could write it by myself, but its not open source.

Comment: On the last line error occurs :     myModsim.RunSolver(myModel)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like after the first run, `myModel` is being set to `Nothing`. Try to step through your code to find out where.

If it is necessary to do so, create a new instance for `myModel` variable.

Comment: well I've tried checking by break points, but the error happens on the last line:" myModsim.RunSolver(myModel) "
unfortunately myModel is the most important object in the code, and its been used frequently through my program.
let me  ask you something!
do you think that this error happens in the next run, because all the objects and variables are filled in the previous run?

Comment: Actually I know null reference means something else, but I'm really confused

Comment: Well, what I think is happening is, after the first run, one (or more) of your variable is set to null that is being used in RunSolver method. Since myModsim is created just a couple of lines back, I feel a property of myModel must be causing this. Check all the properties of myModel for null values.

Answer (score 0):

decyclone has a point. Put a breakpoint and go thorugh it line by line. I would also look at the `XYFileReader` object. 
On the other hand, most of the time I see such error is because I call a function of another object and I do something with an object that is Nothing there. So, check inside `Unit_Conversion_Controller` as well.

When you see the error message, which line is the error on?

Comment: On the last line: 'myModsim.RunSolver(myModel)'.